# Apple Watch Apps Not Available for Download

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-watch, watchos, apple-watch.app

Sometimes, certain apps don't show up in the main menu of the Apple Watch app, in the section where all downloadable apps currently installed on iPhone are displayed. They also disappear from my Apple Watch at those moments. I do have them installed on my iPhone, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

I have an iPhone 6+ running iOS 9.0.1, and an Apple Watch running watchOS 1.0.1.

How do I get the apps to appear? I've so far tried uninstalling and reinstalling the apps on my iPhone from the Apps tab of the Apple Watch app, and restarting both my phone and watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a bug. Try updating to watchOS 2 and see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that's what it was. My watch has been fairly buggy from day one. I updated, and all is well. Thanks!